# How can we Convert JsonWriter To JsonObject in GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Can someone guide me how to convert JsonWriter to JsonObject in GSON without any predefined object.

```
JsonWriter  writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\ravr\\Desktop\\outputJSONSChema.json"));
        writer.setIndent( "    " );
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name( "$schema" ).value( "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#" );
        writer.name( "type" ).value( "object" );
            writer.name("properties");
                writer.beginObject();//1Properties START
                    writer.name( "Country" );
                        writer.beginObject();//2EMP START
                            writer.name( "type" ).value( "array" );
                            writer.name( "minItems" ).value(0);
                            writer.name( "maxItems" ).value("undefined");
                            writer.name( "items" );
                                writer.beginObject();//3 EMP ITEM START
                                    writer.name( "type" ).value( "object" );
                                    writer.name( "properties" );
                                        writer.beginObject();// 

                                            writer.name( "ID" );
                                                writer.beginObject();// 5 EMP ID START
                                                    writer.name( "type" ).value( "String" );
                                                writer.endObject(); // 5 EMP ID END

                                            writer.name( "NAME" );
                                                writer.beginObject();// 5 EMP ID START
                                                    writer.name( "type" ).value( "String" );
                                                writer.endObject(); // 5 EMP ID END
                                        writer.endObject();
                                writer.endObject();//3 EMP ITEM END
                            writer.name( "required" );
                            writer.beginArray();
                                writer.value( "ID" );
                                writer.value( "NAME" );
                            writer.endArray();
                        writer.endObject();//2EMP END
                writer.endObject();//1Properties END
        writer.endObject();
        writer.flush();
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty solution would be to use a `StringWriter` instead of a file writer:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter  writer = new JsonWriter(sw);
// .. writing code

JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(sw.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
```

---

Otherwise you would use something like:

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.add("name", jsonElement);
obj.addProperty("otherName", "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeWriter`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/gson-parent-2.8.0/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeWriter.java) (which extends `JsonWriter`):

```
JsonTreeWriter writer = new JsonTreeWriter();
writer.beginObject();
// write additional JSON data
writer.endObject();
JsonObject obj = (JsonObject)writer.get();
```

This avoids serializing and parsing the JSON data.

Since `JsonTreeWriter` is not part of the public Gson API, you would likely want to copy the `JsonTreeWriter` source into your package (which is easy to do since it only uses public Gson APIs).